# Simple cut out augmentation using tensorflow, issue with assigning values to tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor, data-augmentation

I want to do a simple cut out augmentation on my images but I am not so familiar with tensors so I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the code:

```
def augment_cutout(image, label, size=68, n_squares=1):
    h, w, channels = image.shape
    new_image = image
    for _ in range(n_squares):
        y = np.random.randint(h)
        x = np.random.randint(w)
        y1 = np.clip(y - size // 2, 0, h)
        y2 = np.clip(y + size // 2, 0, h)
        x1 = np.clip(x - size // 2, 0, w)
        x2 = np.clip(x + size // 2, 0, w)
        new_image[y1:y2,x1:x2,:] = 0
    return tf.cast(new_image, tf.float32), label
```

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_func = augment_cutout, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

The above code results in the following error

```
<ipython-input-209-308483a55fd4>:59 augment_cutout  *
        new_image = new_image[y1:y2,x1:x2,:].assign(0)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:401 __getattr__
        self.__getattribute__(name)

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

edit:
I have tried the `tfa.image.random_cutout` function but that does not work either.

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

def random_cut_out(images, labels):
    return tfa.image.random_cutout(images, (64, 64), constant_values = 1), labels

train_dataset = train_ds.map(map_func = preprocess_img, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE) 
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_func = augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(random_cut_out)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: slice index 3 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node 

cutout/strided_slice_2}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, 

begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, 

shrink_axis_mask=1](cutout/Shape, cutout/strided_slice_2/stack, 

cutout/strided_slice_2/stack_1, cutout/strided_slice_2/stack_2)' with input

 shapes: [3], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <3>,

 input[2] = <4>, input[3] = <1>.
```

More info about how I create my dataset:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
builder = tfds.ImageFolder('/content/dataset2')
print(builder.info) 
train_ds, val_ds, test_ds = builder.as_dataset(split=['train', 'val', 'test'], shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True)
```

```
def preprocess_img(image, label, img_shape=160):
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [img_shape, img_shape]) # reshape to img_shape
  return tf.cast(image, tf.float32), label # return (float32_image, label) tuple

BATCH_SIZE = 256
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE


train_dataset = train_ds.map(map_func = preprocess_img, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tfa.image.random_cutout` should do exactly what you want:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

def random_cut_out(images, labels):
    return tfa.image.random_cutout(images, (64, 64), constant_values = 1), labels

flowers = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: img_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, batch_size=32, shuffle=True),
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))

ds = ds.map(random_cut_out)
images, _ = next(iter(ds.take(1)))
image = images[0]

plt.imshow(image.numpy())
```

```
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f85f5692210>
```

[image]

The `tfa.image.random_cutout` function requires a tensor of shape `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. So when you feed single images into your custom function, you need to add an extra dimension:

```py
def random_cut_out(image, label):
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return tf.squeeze(tfa.image.random_cutout(image, (64, 64), constant_values = 1), axis=0), label
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get an error using that method. It should definitely be doable tho, i am just doing something wrong. I edited my question with more information.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Now i dont get an error right there but when i start to train i get the following error; Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected shape=(None, None, None, 3), found shape=(None, 1, 185, 185, 3)

Comment: Updated answer again. Check the function at the bottom. Does it work like that?

Comment: Yes now it works! Thank you!